# Compile mimetic library on Windows?

Tags: c++, mime

I have been searching for a way to compile mimetic library on windows with no luck until now. I need to know how I can do this. I use mingw as my compiler and I also have visual Studio so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem? I just downloaded **mimetic 0.9.7** and then opened the **libmimetic.sln** file in the **win32** folder using *Visual Studio 2012* and compiled the library. It gave me a bunch of warnings but seemed to produce a **.lib** file for me.

I have no idea if the library actually works, but compiling it was not a problem for me.. :)